# actionscript 3 - issues with object speed

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, rotation

So I just got a system working where an object is fired from one moving object at another.

The issue im having now is with the way its currently calculated its making the bullet move slower based on the distance between the object its been shot from and the other object when its initially fired.

Videos to explain.

The speed I want the bullet to stay at : http://gyazo.com/3682d9adde0ed08aa675702d190c0d46.mp4

The speed it goes when objects close:
http://gyazo.com/553b0fb82d89a84f206ea00a9dc8daf0.mp4

Here is the code for the bullet being fired from the yellow object with all the calculations:

```
private function createBullet(): void {
        _pcos = Math.cos((this.rotation) * Math.PI / 180);
        _psin = Math.sin((this.rotation) * Math.PI / 180);
        _startX = this.x - _barrelLength * _pcos;
        _startY = this.y - _barrelLength * _psin;
        _endX = Init._player.x + 1 * _pcos + Math.random() * _bulletSpread -           _bulletSpread * .5;
        _endY = Init._player.y + 1 * _psin + Math.random() * _bulletSpread - _bulletSpread * .5;
        var tempBullet: MovieClip = new Bullet();
        tempBullet.vx = (_endX - _startX);
        tempBullet.vy = (_endY - _startY);
        tempBullet.x = _startX;
        tempBullet.y = _startY;
        tempBullet.rotation = -(Math.atan2(Init._player.x - this.x, Init._player.y - this.y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        tempBullet.maxDistance = _maxDistance;
        _bullets.push(tempBullet);
        stage.addChild(tempBullet);
    }

    public function updateBullets(): void {
        var i: int;
        var tempBullet: MovieClip;
        for (i = 0; i < _bullets.length; i++) {
            tempBullet = _bullets[i];
            tempBullet.x += tempBullet.vx / _bulletSpeed;
            tempBullet.y += tempBullet.vy / _bulletSpeed;
            }
        }
    }
```

If anyone could help with the calculations it would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want your bullets to have the firing object's speed factored in? If yes, set `original` to 1, else 0.

```
    private static const original=1;
    private function createBullet(): void {
        _pcos = Math.cos((this.rotation) * Math.PI / 180);
        _psin = Math.sin((this.rotation) * Math.PI / 180);
        _startX = this.x - _barrelLength * _pcos;
        _startY = this.y - _barrelLength * _psin;
        _endX = Init._player.x + 1 * _pcos + Math.random() * _bulletSpread -               _bulletSpread * .5;
        _endY = Init._player.y + 1 * _psin + Math.random() * _bulletSpread - _bulletSpread * .5;
        var tempBullet: MovieClip = new Bullet();
        var activeAngle:Number=Math.atan2(_endY-_startY,_endX-_startX);
        tempBullet.vx = _bulletSpeed*Math.cos(activeAngle)+original*this.vx;
        tempBullet.vy = _bulletSpeed*Math.sin(activeAngle)+original*this.vy;
        tempBullet.x = _startX;
        tempBullet.y = _startY;
        tempBullet.rotation = -(Math.atan2(Init._player.x - this.x, Init._player.y - this.y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        tempBullet.maxDistance = _maxDistance;
        _bullets.push(tempBullet);
        stage.addChild(tempBullet);
    }

    public function updateBullets(): void {
        var i: int;
        var tempBullet: MovieClip;
        for (i = 0; i < _bullets.length; i++) {
            tempBullet = _bullets[i];
            tempBullet.x += tempBullet.vx;
            tempBullet.y += tempBullet.vy;
        }
    }
}
```

Note, `_bulletSpeed` is measured in pixels per frame, not pixels per second, and is assumed static. The code is untested, please make sure the plus and minus signs are properly set up to your angle system.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your help, I was initially getting the error Line 210, Column 64 : 1119: Access of possibly undefined property vx through a reference with static type code.functions:EnemyYellow. So I just replaced this.vx/this.vy with 1 and its working perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: I was expecting your units to have velocity properties too, not just bullets. If they do, place them into the code, otherwise, drop the `+original*...` part off both assignments.